# Creating Add more Button JavaScript with Bootstrap Select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm developing billing software in core php

i need searchable select tag with add more button

i had created add select using bootstrap

```
<html>

<head>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Bootstrap-select example</h2>
    <p>This uses <a href="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/">https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/</a>
    </p>
    <hr />
  </div>

  <div class="row-fluid">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>1</h4>
        </td>
        <td class="text-semibold text-dark">
          <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" onchange="getModel(this.value);" name="products">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Products</option>
            <?php include "inc/db-connect.php"; $qryyy=m ysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `products`"); if (mysqli_num_rows($qryyy)> 0) { // output data of each row while($rowpro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryyy)) { ?>
            <option data-subtext="(INR <?php echo $rowpro['price']; ?>/-)" value="<?php echo $rowpro['id']; ?>">
              <?php echo $rowpro[ 'pname']; ?>
            </option>
            <?php }} else { ?>
            <option value="" data-subtext=" first!!!">
              <?php echo "Please add products"; ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label id="model-list" style="padding-left: 100px;"></label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" min="1" style="width:70px;">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="price" id="price" min="1" style="width:70px;" readonly>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Above code is working fine but when i had inserted add more javascript
then css is missing from next result of add more script

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 1;
        $('#add').click(function() {
          i++;
          $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><h4>' + i + '</h4></td><td class="text-semibold text-dark"><select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" onchange="getModel(this.value);" name="products"><option value="" disabled selected>Choose Products</option><?php 
            include "inc/db-connect.php"; $qryyy = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `products`");
            if (mysqli_num_rows($qryyy) > 0) {
              // output data of each row
              while ($rowpro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryyy)) { ?>
                < option data - subtext = "(INR <?php echo $rowpro['price']; ?>/-)"
                value = "<?php echo $rowpro['id']; ?>" > <? php echo $rowpro['pname']; ?> < /option><?php 
              }
            } else { ?>
              < option value = ""
              data - subtext = " first!!!" > <? php echo "Please add products"; ?> < /option><?php } ?> < /select > < /td > < td > < label id = "model-list"
              style = "padding-left: 100px;" > < /label></td > < td > < input type = "number"
              name = "qty"
              id = "qty"
              min = "1"
              style = "width:70px;" > < /td><td><input type="number" name="price" id="price" min="1" style="width:70px;" readonly></td > < td > < button type = "button"
              name = "remove"
              id = "'+i+'"
              class = "btn btn-danger btn_remove" > X < /button></td > < /tr>');
            });

          $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
          });

          $('#submit').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: "name.php",
              method: "POST",
              data: $('#add_name').serialize(),
              success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#add_name')[0].reset();
              }
            });
          });

        });
</script>
```

I know my english is too bad, but i need help if any one can understand with my language then please help me out from this...
Or just suggest other way to go through it...
..............................................................................

**EDIT : Codepen Demo : https://codepen.io/singhviku/pen/JzyBVZ**

Comment: Can you make any fiddle/codepen for this so will be easy to check this?

Comment: Sure!!! here is Codepen link : https://codepen.io/singhviku/pen/JzyBVZ

@RohitMittal

Comment: `$('#dynamic_field').append(/* row html */)` should be `$('#dynamic_field > tbody').append(/* row html */)`.

Comment: not work with that @iArcadia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following code, **$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');** after the code of add dynamic fields.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    $('#add').click(function () {
        i++;
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><h4>' + i + '</h4></td><td class="text-semibold text-dark"><select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" onchange="getModel(this.value);" name="products"><option value="" disabled selected>Choose Products</option><option data-subtext="(INR 450/-)" value="1">Hello 1</option><option data-subtext="(INR 450/-)" value="2">Hello 2</option></select></td><td><input type="number" name="rate" id="rate" min="1" style="width:70px;"></td><td><input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" min="1" style="width:70px;"></td><td><input type="number" name="price" id="price" min="1" style="width:70px;" readonly></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
    });
    // Refresh element
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
});
```

**.selectpicker('refresh') Function describes below in official documentation**

To programmatically update a select with JavaScript, first, manipulate the select, then use the refresh method to update the UI to match the new state. This is necessary when removing or adding options, or when disabling/enabling a select via JavaScript.

**I have added codepen updated code.**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZPJqGV

Comment: WOW!!! Great! need one more suggestion. How to add this one in my dynamic_field

***oninput="price.value=parseFloat(rate.value)*parseFloat(qty.value)"***

or any other method to calculate the Price according to rate and quantity?

Comment: sure let me know

Comment: How to add this one in my dynamic_field

***oninput="price.value=parseFloat(rate.value)*parseFloat(qty.value)"***

or any other method to calculate the Price according to rate and quantity?

Comment: but there is not rate field when you create dynamic element

Comment: Sure! Thanks alot @Dipak

Comment: @singhviku It takes some more time and having some work so can you give me time to solve it.

Comment: No problem! i'll try to solve it by my end also

***Thanks Again***

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamically added HTML will not have selectpicker initialization. Thus you need to forcefully call selectpicker after appending HTML as below:

```
$('#dynamic_field').find(".selectpicker:last").selectpicker();
```

Use this code after you append your HTML code. Check `selectpicker` function, if it is not correct, change it according to your jQuery library.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: official documentation shows the proper way Rohit. I suggested please refer to it.